# How to create a vector of bytes from pdf file with ClojureScript?

Tags: byte, pdf-generation, clojurescript

I want to convert a pdf file to a vector of bytes like: [1 23 4 43 .....], using ClojureScript. 
Please, any ideas?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more about the source of the file and the environment where this will run? Is the code running from the command line/server (eg. NodeJS) or in the browser?

Comment: If you want to process the contents of a file you've handled to a browser, you can see some tips on the JavaScript here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58636187/483566 ... those can be written in ClojureScript too.

Comment: My web app is running into Firebase connected to a VM on GCP (where all my code is). The user triggers an event (I don't know if it's relevant, sorry if isn't) wich must load the pdf (stored in Firestore) and translate to bytes (after the dispatch, all the process runs from the server). The pdf file loading works ok. About the environment used by Firebase, I don't know much details.
So, I can load my pdf file , but from this step I don't know how to translate it to bytes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote this quick example that should get you most of what you need for a web version with the HTML5 Files API:

```clj
(defn handle-files [fs]
  (let [file  (aget (.-files fs) 0) ;; the first file
        slice (.slice file 0 100)]  ;; a slice with the first 100 bytes

    ;; The API to get the file contents returns a promise, so we'll update
    ;; the atom when the data is available
    (-> slice .text (.then #(swap! file-info assoc-in [:contents] %)))

    ;; Most of the file info is available right away
    (reset! file-info {:name (.-name file)
                       :size (.-size file)
                       :type (.-type file)})))

;; App initialization

(defn mount-root []
  (rdom/render [example-app] (.getElementById js/document "app"))

  ;; register fn to check on the file[s] we want the browser to scan
  (-> (.getElementById js/document "input")
      (.addEventListener "change" #(handle-files (.-target %)) false)))
```

You can find a working example on this repo: https://github.com/dfuenzalida/cljs-files-api